# How to Execute a sub task code , when whole code is gradle based

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, build.gradle

I have a java project which uses gradle as built tool. There is a small sub task which does not need whole project build and is independent of whole project.
It has a separate main class with `main` method.

Although this code too needs to get its dependencies from the common project's build.gradle.

The main project build and run is there in place with gradle. 
I need to give a separate single point exclusively for my "small sub task" from where people can execute my "small sub task" (like a .bat file or something similar).

I tried writing a .bat file which tries to compile the classes of my "small sub task" but compilation fails due to dependent libs not found as those are needed to be referenced from build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre], please? What is the layout of your project and what do your `build.gradle` file(s) look like? I'm also not entirely certain what your "small sub-task" is supposed to be doing nor how it relates to the rest of the build—could you clarify?

Comment: I can not give you the gradle.build file as its not with me but due to some internal legacy code gradle invokes sbt build. the "small sub task" is supposed to be running as a separate process sending repetative message on the serial COM port